# How to get the UTC offset from a timezone string using pytz?

Tags: python, datetime, pytz

I am trying to get the UTC offset as a string from my timezone using the Python library pytz.

I am defining it as follows:

```
import pytz
tz = pytz.timezone('Africa/Cairo')
```

Now, I want to get '+02:00' from the `tz` variable, as that is the corresponding UTC offset for Africa/Cairo.

How can I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `datetime` to get current date/time in given timezone and then extract UTC offset,

```
import pytz
import datetime
tz = pytz.timezone('Africa/Cairo')


print(datetime.datetime.now(tz).utcoffset().total_seconds()/3600)
# output,
2.0
```